# Powershell DCOM Excel fails under Task Scheduler, but works at command prompt

Tags: excel, powershell, dcom

I have a PS1 (Powershell v.5) script with a line:

**$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application**

This works on my Win10 laptop at command prompt or when run by Task Scheduler.   My user is Local with Admin.  Task is set to run whether user is logged on or not.

I have a new desktop, also Win10, I've copied the script there and imported the job from my laptop to the desktop's Task Scheduler.  My user is Local with Admin.

It works at a command prompt, or in Visual Code.

It fails when run by the Task Scheduler (right-click job, select Run):

error **Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).**

It will work if i edit task to run only when user is logged on.

Summ:

On Laptop, User1 (Local Admin) works both Command Prompt and under Task Scheduler.

On Desktop, User1 (Local Admin) works at Command Prompt, fails under Task Scheduler, unless task is set to run only when user is logged on.

Someone else said i need
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop and C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop.   No help there.

I want it to wake and run even when i'm not logged in (as it does on my old laptop)

Code looks like (this is just something banged together to show the problem)

```
Start-Transcript -Path "C:\Users\User1\TryExcelPS1\transcript.txt"

$logfile = "C:\Users\User1\TryExcelPS1\tmp.log"

Function Log {
    param([string] $s) 
    $line = $(Get-Date -Format s) + ": " + $s                                                               # date like 2018-02-18T22:38:44
    if($logfile -ne $null) {  Add-Content -Path $logfile -value $line  }    # write to log file
    Write-Host $line
}

Log "Starting"
    # now start our own Excel
    $WorkBook = "C:\Users\User1\TryExcelPS1\TryExcel.xlsx"
    $SheetName = "Running"
    try{ 
        Log "Getting ComObject Excel.Application"
        $objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application   <<----- FAILS under Task Sched
        Log "Got Excel Object"

        Log "Setting visible"
        $objExcel.Visible = $true
        Start-Sleep -milliseconds 500
        
        Log "Setting Workbook"
        $WorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($WorkBook)
        $WorkSheet = $WorkBook.sheets.item($SheetName)
        $val = $WorkSheet.Cells(1, 1).Text
    
        Log "FillVangExcel: Excel check val=$val"
     
        $today = Get-Date -format("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss")
        Log "Writing $today..."
    
        $WorkSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value2 = $today
                        
        Start-Sleep 7       # so just pause
    
        Log "Saving/Closing Excel object"
        $Workbook.Close($TRUE)            # True to SaveChanges
        $objExcel.Quit()   
        $rco = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($objExcel)
        Log "Stopping Excel process"
        # Stop-Process -n Excel
        Remove-Variable objExcel
        Log "Excel Done"
    }

    catch{  $theError = $_
            $theMsg = $Error[0].Exception.Message
            Log "Error: failed to start Excel, error $_"
            Log "Error: failed to start Excel, msg = $theMsg"
            Write-Warning "Failed to start Excel"
        }
    
    
    Log ...Done.
    Stop-Transcript
```

Comment: Did you try creating this folder? `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files`

Comment: Doug, Thanks for the suggestion.  No luck.  I did not have that folder.  I created it and added some code to my script to ensure my user could create/write/read a file in that folder.  Works at command prompt, same failure under the Task Manager :(

Comment: What about this one? `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache`  also you may consider creating the 32bit as well like was done for Desktop.  I don't believe running any MS office com objects as a scheduled task is supported so even if you get it to work it may just stop working. Have you considered using the great ImportExcel module by Doug Finke?

Comment: Thanks again, Doug.  I did not have that one.  I added it and ensured that my user has rights.  No joy.  I already had "C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache" so no joy there either.

Comment: i have become abundantly aware that this is not such a good idea.  This is a little personal project that gets local temperature every day and adds a line to an excel file.  There are some other columns that average by week and month, and lag a year and two years for comparison.  Nothing important.
The scheduled tasks wakes the computer and runs the powershell script to log into a website to scrape some numbers, then DCOM Excel to add the numbers to the spreadsheet.  It has two weak points:  scraping a website that "improves" (changes) and running excel.  Other than that it's good :)

Comment: Seriously the importexcel module is what you need. It doesn’t even require excel to be installed. It’s as easy as Export-CSV except it’s Export-Excel